# How to collect data from LTspice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, data

I am trying to collect data from a circuit and use that data for a regression analysis to get results. For my analysis purpose, one input needs to have different output (as the circuit I am using is the chaotic circuit).

My input is a sinewave with an amplitude of 3V and at 10k frequency. So when I export the data from LTspice, input changes very fast, and even I put very small max step time it doesn't give the same input values like for example for the 1st period of the sine wave the transient analysis collects data when input is at 0.01 then for the other period it's collecting at 0.0139 or something like that.

So, is there a way that I could collect the same input for all the periods of the sinewave?

The circuit I am using:
[image]

Thank you in advance, I couldn't get to upload an excel file but I am happy to explain more if needed.

Comment: Does that mean that you would like to have a constant time step size?

Comment: Yes. Like, let's say starting from 0.001 going to 3 with a time step of 0.001, and then going back to -3.

Answer (score 3):

LTspice (like most SPICEs) doesn't perform a `.TRAN` analysis with a fixed timestep, and that's because of the way the solver works. There are exceptions, though (e.g. see [compumike's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/558835/95619)). But if you can tolerate an external utility, there exists one called [ltsputil.exe](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_yahoo/Util/ltsputil). It can be found in the LTspice group (registration needed, to avoid spammers).

If you're using LTspice XVII, then you will have to first run [ltsputil17raw4_1_1.zip](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_yahoo/Util/ltsputil/ltsputil17raw4_1_1.zip) because XVII uses UTF for the `.raw` files, then use the regular [ltsputil_2_95a.zip](https://groups.io/g/LTspice/files/z_yahoo/Util/ltsputil/ltsputil_2_95a.zip). It will not magically re-calculate all the values to be exact, instead, it will interpolate such that the available data-time points will be evenly spaced. Therefore, as the others have pointed out, imposing a small(er) timestep and/or using `.opt plotwinsize=0` will be needed for reliable results.

For your case, this is the command line that you could use:

```
/path/to/ltsputil.exe -e simulation.raw output.raw 1001
```

which converts the input file `simulation.raw` to the newly created `output.raw` which will have 1001 equidistant points. There are other options and examples, to make ASCII files, linear interpolation, etc; see the file `ltsputil_help.txt` from the archive. There is also a GUI mode in the folder I linked, I never used it (or if I have, I have already forgotten).

---

There are at least two other ways to do it:

1. By perfoming FFT on the desired trace (`.opt plotwinsize=0` & imposed timestep will help), then IFFT (FFT on the FFT), which will generate back the time domain response with equispaced samples. LTspice's proprietary algorithm allows for a non-power-of-2 FFT points, which means you can specify the desired number of samples easily. The catch is that the first FFT will be done on an internally quadratically interpolated waveform, so that will be similar to using `ltsputil.exe`, but slightly more convenient since you're not leaving LTspice's grounds. The drawback is the leakage if not enough points are chosen:

[image: leak]

2. Export the waveform as a `.wav` file. The drawback is that the limits are `+1` and `-1`, and anything beyond will be hard clipped. The advantage is that you can specify any number of bits (from 1 to 32) and any sample rate (from 1 to 4294967295).

As far as the original answer is concerned, you can improve the time resolution with a simple trick: add a `PULSE()` voltage source with `PULSE 0 1 0 {tr} {T-tr} 0 {T}`, where `T` is the period of the sampling, and `tr` is the rising time. A value for `tr` of ~100~1000x less than `T` is a good choice, which doesn't slow down the simulation too much while having a sufficiently small resolution. The time points for the source will be known to the solver, so for all the times `tr` is encountered the solver will be forced to reduce the timestep to accomodate the sharp transition, thus providing a cluster of small-spaced points, something like this:

[image: trick]

This will help further processing with `ltsputil.exe`, by providing a denser information region to which to apply the interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add this to your circuit:

`options plotwinsize=0`

From [LTspiceHelp](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_OPTIONS_Set_simulator_options.htm):

[image]

Comment: I tried it but it didn't help. Can you please explain a little on how to use it. I think I might be using it wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @BirajShakya as pointed out by two other answers, this option can be used with other options or external tools to get better results. In fact, I think that merging the two with compression disable option will provide an excellent result: use very small time steps and interpolate (if needed). Not using a constant time-step is, in fact, a feature that provides better results. Please let us know if the results were ok.

Comment: I am still working on it. My results are better but still not quite uniform with the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

For the options setting `plotwinsize=0` to have effect on your simulation (that is, to disable window compression), you have to tell the simulator that you want to print at a constant time step. To do so, you should indicate the desired `Tstep` as a parameter in the `.tran` command:

```
*you've written down: 
.tran 0    2 0 1e-9 

*you should write:
.tran 1e-9 2 0 1e-9
```

Notice that because you want to cancel waveform compression and you specify the maximum timestep `1e-9` in the fourth parameter of your `.tran` control statement, you **must** also specify `Tstep`. Do not set it zero, if you want to have a predetermined timestep in the output data. For your convenience, I am citing [the excerpt from the LTspice help](http://www.ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/_TRAN_Do_a_non_linear_transient_analysis.htm) in full (emphasis is mine):

> Syntax: .TRAN <Tstep> <Tstop> [Tstart [dTmax]] [modifiers]
>
> .TRAN  [modifiers]
>
> The first form is the traditional .tran SPICE command. Tstep is the
> plotting increment for the waveforms but is also used as an initial
> step-size guess. LTspice uses waveform compression, so this parameter
> is of little value and can be omitted or set to zero. Tstop is the
> duration of the simulation. Transient analyses always start at time
> equal to zero. However, if Tstart is specified, the waveform data
> between zero and Tstart is not saved. This is a means of managing the
> size of waveform files by allowing startup transients to be ignored.
> The final parameter dTmax, is the maximum time step to take while
> integrating the circuit equations. **If Tstart or dTmax is specified,
> Tstep must be specified**.

The directions are somewhat ambiguous, but the experiments with settings support the conclusions.

The setting of `option plotwinsize=0` and of `Tstep` and `dTmax` parameters in a `.tran` statement does not guarantee per se a uniform timestep of the output, because *the simulator prefers precision over user's dataprocessing convenience*, but the timestep of 1ns is sufficient for simulations with 2N2222 transistors and 10KHz sources, and you will have equidistant data samples.

But pay attention that the `.tran` command with parameters set like these would produce a text file with `2s/1ns = 2E+9` (two billion) lines of data. It is not your goal, a file that large. So, you decide to set a timestep not that small (1ns), but, say, respecting a Nyquist frequency of your voltage source and conforming to the circuit's RC time constants. To respect the Nyquist frequency, your timestep must be under 0.025 ms.

Your simulation would not tolerate that large a timestep in the entire time interval: to provide a decent precision, the simulator would decrease the timestep when necessary. The text export of simulation data would contain entries with non-uniform time intervals: the simulator prefers precision over plotting convenience.

You can try to find the smallest timestep in your data and use this value for `Tstep` and `dTmax`, but this would defeat your purpose of fighting very large outputs. Another option is to partition the simulation interval `[0, Tstop]` to sub-intervals of fast-changing and relatively-slow-changing values, but it requires an effort sometimes equivalent to manual processing of simulation data. As a remedy to this situation, I recommend you to have what the simulator gives to you and postprocess this data to any form you like with a program, which you can write in a computer language of your choice. For example, your program can perform decimation and interpolation, and you can do it even with Excel VBA, although MATLAB or Python are better suited for this purpose.

Comment: `2E+9` is 2 billion, not 2 trillion. Still, your point holds -- that's way too many data points for this :)

Comment: @compumike Ok, US 'billion', European 'milliard', corrected

Comment: I tried with the Tstep but still didn't quite get the uniform space between the input data. It is way better than the data I was getting before so thank you so much for the reply. I will see if there is anything else I can do to make it better and precise.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get the data you're looking for with the embedded CircuitLab simulator:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg5o8S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is currently configured with a 5ms simulation with 1us time step. This time step 1us divides evenly into your function generator's period, 100us. As a result, you'll get exactly 100 samples per sine period.

Run the simulation, then click **Export Plot CSV** in the upper right of the window:

[image: CSV spreadsheet]

Comment: Does the solver do it natively, or interpolated?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but I am looking to step the input not the time.

Comment: "Step the input not the time" -- it's not clear to me what you're looking for here, and this may impact other people's reading of your question. A DC Sweep can step over an input voltage. However your circuit is AC-coupled and so this won't be too useful for you.

Comment: Sorry about that. I will try to explain the questions clearly next time. And thank you for the reply.